# Button.titleLabel error in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to compare the title that I have in a button so that if it is compared to another it does a certain thing or not. I'm using the .setTitle function but I think in swift3 it gives error and I can not find the why. Then I leave a catch of the error to make it easier to see it and also the code itself. Thanks for the help

[image]

```
@IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: Any) 
{
    if(_login_button.titleLabel?.text == "OKEY")
    {
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")

        LoginToDo()
        return
    }

    let username = _username.text
    let password = _password.text

    if(username == "" || password == "")
    {
        return
    }

    DoLogin(username!, password!)
}
```

Comment: It is because of the `sender` you are using in the action. It should be `UIButton` instead of `Any`

Comment: Please check what is mean by IBOutlets and IBActions, you are used wrong this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your `@IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: Any)` to **you need to type cast from Any to UIButton** `@IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: UIButton)`

```
@IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: UIButton) 
      {
      if(sender.titleLabel?.text == "OKEY")
        {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get button as below , now you access function name instead of sender

```
@IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: Any) 
        let button: UIButton = sender as! UIButton


      if(button.titleLabel?.text == "OKEY")
        {
    }
}
```

Comment: @IBAction func _login_button(_ sender: Any) {
        
        if((sender as AnyObject).titleLabel??.text == "OKEY")
        {
            
            let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
            preferences.removeObject(forKey: "session")
            
            LoginToDo()
            return
            
        }

Comment: Swift corrects what you have written to me and tells me to put it like this, okay?

Comment: why u taken too much of code, i optimized ur answer ,

Comment: get button and replace it in your condition.

Comment: Why put your code swift told me to put it so because it gave error

Answer (score 0):

_login_button is @IBAction you have to create the button for @IBOutlet of button

Answer (score 0):

If you get this error as per screen shot, you need to type cast from Any to UIButton and then use titleLabel property.